# ¿Cuál es el script usado el paquete scheduleR de R para programar una tarea al mes?

Tags: r, rstudio

Buen día a todos, al utilizar el paquete `taskscheduleR` puedo correr determinado script en cierto momento del día (**es su funcionalidad**).
*No se cuales son los argumentos para que la tarea sea por ejemplo los 5 de cada mes*.
Entendería que sería algo así, sin embargo no compila.

> myscript <- system.file("extdata", "helloworld.R", package = "taskscheduleR")
>
> taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript_sun", rscript = myscript, 
>                        schedule = "MONTHLY", modifier =1, months='FEB',starttime = "00:01", days = '5')

Comment: Jose, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo incluir un [mcve] para que tu pregunta tenga mayor aceptacion.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? ¿Has tenido algún problema? ¿Cual? te lo pregunto, por que, por la documentación no parece demasiado complicado definir lo que buscas.

Comment: Realicé algunos cambios, muchas gracias Kenny y Patricio por ayudarme en mejorar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según  la [documentación](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/taskscheduleR/versions/1.1/topics/taskscheduler_create), si quiseramos programar un Script para que se ejecute todos los meses el día 5 a las 17:00 horas, deberíamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
myscript <- system.file("extdata", "helloworld.R", package = "taskscheduleR")
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "Nombre de la tarea", 
                     rscript = myscript,
                     schedule = "MONTHLY",
                     starttime = "17:00",
                     days = "5")
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio, fue de mucha ayuda, en la lap del trabajo corrió añadiendo comillas en el argumento 'days'.  En el servidor me funcionó añadiendo 'startdate' en formato dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Si, efectivamente `days` espera un vector de caracteres, gracias por la aclaración.